# Why does the concept of a derivative of a polynomial remain useful when generalized to arbitrary fields?

Tags: calculus, abstract-algebra, polynomials

The derivative of a polynomial is useful in algebra because of its algebraic properties. However, the definition itself originally comes from analysis. It seems like too big a coincidence that an analytic definition continues to be so useful even in contexts where the concepts of limits and (analytic) derivatives no longer make sense. Is there an explanation for this?

An example of how such an explanation could be provided is:

1. An "algebraic" definition of the derivative of a polynomial over a field $F$, for example as the unique polynomial satisfying some property, rather than just by providing the formula with no explanation.
2. An explanation as to why this also happens to give the rate of change when $F=\mathbb R$. For example, maybe a proof that the rate of change equals the algebraic derivative, but which doesn't involve explicitly calculating the limit, it just shows that the rate of change must satisfy some property which characterizes the algebraic derivative.

Comment: Related / possible duplicate: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/307439/

Comment: @Sal I'd say that's pretty much an exact duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

The first algebraic idea that comes to mind is the multiplicity of roots when $(P,P')$ is a non constant polynomial.