# Elementary question about roots with multiplicity of a polynomial.

Tags: derivatives, polynomials, roots

How do i prove following lemma in general:

Let $x_0$ be a root with multiplicity $m$ of a polynomial $f$, then $\forall k\in \{0,1,...,m-1\}: f^{(k)}(x_0)=0$.

Comment: And where is your own work on the problem?

Comment: Please add some context to your Question.  Proving something "in general" is not always meaningful.  Are you considering polynomials as *real* functions, or are you considering them as formal *algebraic* expressions?  The meaning of "roots" and derivatives can vary accordingly.

Comment: @hardmath Really?

Comment: @egreg: The [formal derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_derivative) of polynomials has been discussed [here previously](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/307439/appearance-of-formal-derivative-in-algebra).  Proving "in general" suggests an especial care for what definitions are used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT:**

$$f(x) = (x-x_0)^mg(x)$$

where $g(x_0) \not = 0$.

Comment: @Downvoter What is wrong with my answer?

Comment: Nothing, but somebody on the site thinks that answers to bad questions need downvotes.

Comment: @egreg Nevermind. The quality of the answer isn't even remotely connected to the quality of the question. Moreover it's not like I gave the OP a full answer, it was just a direction. On top of that I consider downvoting an answer equivalent to saying the answer isn't good or wrong. I'm willing to debate my answer, no matter whether it's wrong or right. Debate can only be useful, in my opinion. That's what I was trying to spark with my comment.

Comment: Hi, Stefan4024.  I am your downvoter.  I downvoted *because* it is not a full answer.  You could have easily posted this as a Comment and I might have upvoted.  It is not the sort of content that meets site standards for Answers.  I'm not interested in a debate.

Comment: @hardmath First of all I appreciate your feedback, as too often people decide not to reply to my "calls". Nevertheless I tend to post hints, instead of full answers for homework questions or questions where the OP presented no effort. On the other side I respect your opinion and your right to downvote my answer. And as you're not interested in a debate, let's leave the talk whether my answer is appropriate or not for another time ;)